# Should the salting and hashing of a password be performed in C# server-side code or T-SQL code in the database? (For ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, hash, asp.net-core-mvc

All I want to know is, should salting and hashing a password be done by C# code or in T-SQL? I can see there is a hashbytes function in T-SQL, but there is also the Identity framework and the System.Security.Cryptography functions. What is the standard way of doing it? And are there any advantages/disadvantages of one method over the other? Thanks

PS: I know about salting, hashing etc, no need to explain what that is, just whether to do in C# or T-SQL.

Comment: The plain text password should never reach the database; if it does it's already too late as anyone with the right permiy could read the statements executed.

Comment: This may come handy:
https://medium.com/@mehanix/lets-talk-security-salted-password-hashing-in-c-5460be5c3aae

Comment: Hi, thanks, I hadn't thought that if the plain-text reaches the database, but isn't actually stored there could pose a problem, but I guess it could and adds an extra vulnerability. Thanks for the web-link, looks very much like what I have done before in PHP (a long long time ago). So main take-away, don't salt and hash in T-SQL, do it in C#. Raises the question then, why have functions to do that in T-SQL at all. Hmm?

Comment: And another link that might come in handy: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm